# Smart/casual dress is encouraged with longs/shoes a must : What is "longs"?

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

A community-edited travel guide about [Colombo](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Colombo) (Sri Lanka) has this paragraph:

> Most nightclubs may charge admission and smart/casual dress is encouraged with longs/shoes a must.

What does "longs" mean here?

Online dictionaries I tried did not have the term.

Comment: One thing to note is that Sri Lankan English is more closely related to older, formal British English.  Few Sri Lankans have English as their first language, and, as a result, it has some peculiarities not found in modern American English.

Answer (score 21):

I've never heard of this either in the US. I was able to find it in the Collins Dictionary online. It appears to be BrE and what we in the US would call "pants".  Maybe someone else can speak to how common it is in BrE.

> [longs](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/longs) in British
>   (lɒŋz )
>   plural noun
>   1. full-length trousers

---

Edit:

BrE users are reporting that this might not be BrE and that it might be Indian English. I also have a person saying that they've heard it used a couple of times by the elderly in Britain.

I found an entry in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long) ("long trousers"), which leads me to suspect this usage might be dated, obsolete.

In any case, "longs" seems like a reasonable opposite of "shorts". However, as far as learning contemporary, mainstream English is concerned, I recommend sticking to "trousers" or "pants" depending on your audience.

Comment: I'd bet it's Indian English. It sure isn't British, nor would anyone need to specify "long trousers" for any occasion that said 'smart casual'. Shorts simply wouldn't fall inside that definition. Holiday destinations might need to clarify further, to prevent the hordes of Brits in shorts, sandals, no t-shirt & a large capacity for sangria; but nowhere else.

Comment: Never heard "longs" used like that in British English. I agree that this could be Indian English use.

Comment: I have heard this saying only a couple of times in Britain, though mostly from older members or society (think 65+)

Comment: The usage in British English comes from school uniform codes in the early to mid 20th century. Younger boys would wear short trousers and older ones once they reached secondary school age wore long trousers. Since this stopped being the case in the 1960s no one uses those terms anymore except older people as J.Doe suggests.

Comment: I heard both "long trousers" and "short trousers" spoken by older teachers at my school in S.E. England in the late 1980s. It was unusual back then (I initially thought "short trousers" referred to the skinny 'drainpipe' jeans that were in fashion back then!) and I haven't heard anyone use those terms again.

Comment: Not AuE either, but I have heard 'legs', as in "put your legs on, or you'll catch cold".  I'd guess it's Ceylon English

Comment: @Sarriesfan I've never heard 'longs' used in that context in Britain --- it was always 'long trousers', in full. (And then if you go back a few decades it was 'bags', still used occasionally in the context of 'debagged' today.)

Comment: @David Given I too have heard long trousers more commonly, in reference to this I would suspect that 'longs' was a rare variant used in a particular part of the Britain.

Answer (score 13):

Longs are the opposite of shorts.

As to its usage - I am a native British English speaker born in the seventies and I've never heard it in 40+ years. The most common word would be *trousers* (or, in some regions you may hear the more informal word *pants*, but in other regions this word is reserved for underwear), and if needed we sometimes clarify that they need to be smart by saying *smart trousers*. It is generally accepted that "smart" dress excludes shorts.

However, while this word might be in a British English dictionary, I'm not sure your guide is written by someone speaking British English, or any good form of English, as the term "smart/casual" is written with a slash. This makes it look like an "either" option, yet the two are quite different. Surely they mean "*smart casual*"?

The term "*smart casual*" is widely misunderstood. What it actually is changes with time and fashion, but generally speaking it means a smart form of dress that is not *formal* like a mans suit or a woman's cocktail dress. For a man it means trousers (*not* jeans) with a shirt and shoes. But many think it means combining smart things, like a shirt, with something casual like jeans and trainers/sneakers. This is thought of by some to be a massive fashion mistake.

My point is, whenever you see "smart casual" on an invitation, for the reason given above it is not uncommon to see some kind of clarification such as "no jeans", or even specifying tuxedos or ball gowns / cocktail dresses for formal events. In your example, they are trying to say "no shorts" by specifying that long trousers are expected.

Comment: This reads as if "pants" is a less formal word for "trousers" in British English. Don't say "smart pants" for a British reader, unless you want him to come in his underwear!  I've edited slightly.

Comment: @JamesK I rolled your edit back because in the north of England we *do* use "pants" to mean trousers, not just underwear. But I have added this as a note.

Comment: Ok. I disagree. Pants is exclusively underwear to me.

Comment: @JamesK You should get further north from time to time. "Pants" may be more American but it *is* used for trousers in some regions. Also for pyjama bottoms, usually called pyjama pants, not pyjama trousers.

Comment: In the very early 70s, when I started school, it was still common practice to refer to short trousers (infant school years) as "shorts" (still is) but also to refer to long trousers (junior school years) as "longs". This was SE England though. Being as old as I am I would still recognize "longs" to mean long trousers, but wouldn't actually expect to ever see (or hear) it in use these days.

Comment: @Spratty: I started school in the early 60's, and I don't recall hearing "longs" to mean "long trousers".  School in Bromley, Suffolk, and Huntingdonshire.

Comment: @MartinBonner: South-east Essex for me. It was common at my school (and in the cube, now I think of it) at least - more than that I can't say :-)

Comment: As another 70s born Brit I recognise and use the term "long trousers" to distinguish from shorts. Surprised it is perceived as archaic. "Longs" is not a term I recognise though.

Comment: Re transatlantic pants: remember that in the US, Superman wears his pants on the inside, while in the UK he wears his pants on the outside.

Answer (score 6):

This is (or was) fairly common in NZ English or Australian English, where we have lengths of trousers as:

- Short shorts ("Daisy Dukes")

  Shorts (what we normally wear, because sunshine)

  3/4 lengths ("Knickerbockers")

  Longs (winter clothing in NZ, or to get into fancy nightclubs overseas)

Types of longs include

- Slacks ("Chinos" in US English I think)

  Cords ("Corduroy")

  Leather trousers (for motorcycles) - not "smart casual"

  Jeans - not "smart casual"

Underwear would be "grundies" "undergruts" "underpants" etc. not "pants", but probably not expected to be on view in "smart casual" parties, i.e. no "calvin klein"/"aussiebum"/"bjorn borg" on display.

Comment: Needs references - at least in Oz I've never heard someone use 'knickerbockers' or 'longs'.

Comment: US English has the term "slacks" as well, but after being thoroughly confused by it for years I've come to the conclusion that it means "pants that aren't jeans or shorts". I don't know if that affects your translation or not.

Comment: I've known several Brits who said the phrase "khaki pants" would mean "dirty underwear".  "Khaki" after all is a brownish color and "pants" means "underpants".

Comment: @KamilDrakari I'll guess that the term 'slacks' has something to do with how they hang.  When you get pants fitted for length, they check that there's a little 'break' where they lay on the shoes.

Comment: re US: The term 'slacks' is widely used.  It basically means nice pants you wouldn't do yard work in.  I'm not really clear on exactly what 'chinos' are.  I gather they are some sort of pants (khakis?) that the fashion industry markets at us every 5 years or so.

Comment: So people in New Zealand and Australia know who Daisy Duke is?  Fascinating.

Comment: @JimmyJames "Chino" is just a type of fabric made of cotton. They're much lighter than khakis. When I think of pants that can't otherwise be classified as anything else, they're usually chinos. Typically they're solid-color and are appropriate for more casual workplaces as well as going out.

Comment: In US women's wear (the only kind I'm familiar with), I would expect "slacks" to usually be something that has a crease or at least is meant to be ironed. Trousers are basically slacks, but probably in a nicer fabric (wool or silk blend, at least) and a higher price-point (slacks might be the same, but can also be made from polyester and sold at Wal-Mart). Chinos and khakis are both more casual, probably a light- or mid-weight cotton, and mostly worn by men (though they do exist for women) who are either dressing down from business wear or up from jeans.